# cups printer prints raw postscript

Tags: cups, postscript, ppd

I have an OKI B430d printer, which is connected to an Odroid C2 (a single-board computer similar to the Raspberry Pi) via USB. The Odroid runs Arch Linux Arm with a cups server, so every device in the local network can use the printer.
The printer is configured as RAW printer.

My desktop computer runs Arch Linux with a cups instance, too. This cups instance connects to the Odroid via ipp and also has the ppd file for the printer.

Now to the issue I started noticing ~8 months ago:
Sometimes the printer would print a blank page containing only

```
--------------------------
```

or

```
.0 0
    %-------------------------------------------------
```

or

```
source 1.0 0
             %-------------------------------------------------
```

The issue also occured when printing from a different PC than mine (but also running cups on Arch Linux).

Yesterday I printed some more PDFs and this time the printer printed a blank page containing the following in front of 3 jobs:

```
OKI_Driver_Procedure_Patch_Resource 1.0 0
                                         %------------------------------------
```

Finally something to search for! I found a PPD file which contained a similar line, so I searched the PPD file I use for the printer for the line and found it on line 108: https://www.oki.com/eu/printing/support/drivers-and-utilities/?id=46262901FZ01

Today, I printed a [test PDF](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Test.pdf) after enabling debug logging for both cups instances. I pasted the debug logs here: https://gist.github.com/jkhsjdhjs/aab53920040f62b43c878c74a61860ea

One thing I did change for the printer locally was `lpadmin -p <printer> -o pdftops-renderer-default=pdftops`. It didn't work without it, but I don't think that's the cause.

Let me know if there's more info I can provide.
Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT: So I connected the printer directly to my PC, same issue.

Then I created a test printing queue using the same PPD but printing the postscript output to a file instead. I noticed that the output that I suspected to from the PPD file is also in the postscript document that is sent to the printer:

```
%%BeginResource: OKI_Driver_Procedure_Patch_Resource 1.0 0
%-------------------------------------------------
%% OKI Driver Procedure ver 1.0
%%    Date: Dec. 27, 2005  Edt: 03
%-------------------------------------------------

/OK@setpagedevice_sadj where {pop}{
 /OK@setpagedevice_sadj /setpagedevice load def
/OK@PageDevice_Install_proc currentpagedevice /Install get def
<< /Install { mark currentstrokeadjust OK@PageDevice_Install_proc setstrokeadjust cleartomark } >> setpagedevice
}ifelse
```

So for some reason the printer fails to correctly interpret the PostScript sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably, that the printer is unable to interpret the PostScript generated by ghostscript, although the PPD file is correct.

Since the manufacturer provides a PCL driver for windows, I tried configuring the printer as a generic PCL printer in cups, which works way better!